# Web server crashes when spammed with F5

Tags: dart

I made a simple web server but it crashes every time I am refreshing page many times in a short time. I just enter 127.0.0.1:8080 in my browser and then spam with F5. Here is the code to reproduce this issue:

```dart
void main()
{
  HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
  server.addRequestHandler((req) => true, handleGET);
  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8080);
}

void handleGET(HttpRequest req, HttpResponse res)
{
  var requestedFile = ".${req.path}";

  if(req.path == "/")
  {
    requestedFile = requestedFile.concat("index.html");
  }

  File file = new File(requestedFile);
  file.exists().then((bool found) {
    if(found)
    {
      file.openInputStream().pipe(res.outputStream);
    }
    else
    {
      res.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
      res.outputStream.close();
    }
  });
}
```

The error I get is following:

```
Unhandled exception:
StreamException: Stream closed
#0      _SocketOutputStream._write (dart:io:6017:30)
#1      _HttpResponse._writeHeader (dart:io:5981:18)
#2      _HttpRequestResponseBase._ensureHeadersSent (dart:io:2696:19)
#3      _HttpResponse._streamClose (dart:io:2921:23)
#4      _HttpOutputStream.close (dart:io:3078:36)
#5      _pipe.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:6271:28)
#6      _BaseDataInputStream._checkScheduleCallbacks.issueCloseCallback (dart:io:6231:59)
#7      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6804:28)
#8      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6812:7)
#9      _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:6820:23)
#10     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:37:92)
```

Often before this mayor exception I receive a bunch of warnings like WSASend failed: 10053 but those don't crash the server. I work on Windows if this problem is related to some specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are hitting reload very quickly, your code ends up trying to write to a socket that has already been closed. Hence, you should probably catch StreamException and just ignore it. It could be argued that the io library should help you out a bit more. I just filed this bug:

http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7334&thanks=7334&ts=1355280746

Comment: Please, could you show me how to catch this exception? Also I can get a SocketIOException: Write failed (OS Error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. errno = 10053) even if my matcher function return false always server.addRequestHandler((req) => false, handleGET);

Comment: To catch the exception, wrap your code in a try { } block - see this gist: https://gist.github.com/4272378

Comment: @ChrisBuckett, since this is asynchronous code, I really don't think using a try block is going to help. That's because the execution happens in a callback that gets run when the try block is no longer on the stack. I'm having a hard time trying out this code because of this bug (http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7356), however, I think the right thing to do is to add a server.onError handler.

Comment: Aah - yes,  I was in naive try / catch mode. Thanks Shannon.